# Another way to output this?

Tags: java, output, root, equation

I was wondering if there was a way to get a certain output. For my code, I am using the Newton Raphson method to solve the three equations. I have to display the root of it at the certain iteration.

As you can you see from the code, I have the output as "The root is *ROOT* after *COUNTER* iterations." Right now, I type in the root and the counter into the code AFTER I get the answer from running the program. Is there a way I can have an output like " "The root is " + root " after " + counter + " iterations." "? In other words, how can I have the program find the root and print it, instead of me having to type it in manually along with the counter?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //x^3 + x^2 + 1
    //2x^3 - 2x^2 - 2
    //3x^3 + 3x^2 + 3

    newrap1();
    newrap2();
    newrap3();
}
public static double func1(double x)
    {
        double f1;
        f1 = Math.pow(x, 3) + Math.pow(x, 2) + 1;
        return f1;
    }
public static double func2(double x)
    {
        double f2;
        f2 = 2*Math.pow(x, 3) - 2*Math.pow(x, 2) - 2;
        return f2;
    }
public static double func3(double x)
    {
        double f3;
        f3 = 3*Math.pow(x, 3) + 3*Math.pow(x, 2) + 3;
        return f3;
    }
public static double der1(double x)
    {
        double d1;
        d1 = 3*Math.pow(x, 2) + 2*x;
        return d1;
    }
public static double der2(double x)
    {
        double d2;
        d2 = 6*Math.pow(x, 2) - 4*x;
        return d2;
    }
public static double der3(double x)
    {
        double d3;
        d3 = 9*Math.pow(x, 2) + 6*x;
        return d3;
    }
public static void newrap1()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func1(x)/der1(x);
            if (diff == 0) return;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);

        }
        System.out.println("The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
public static void newrap2()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func2(x)/der2(x);
            if (diff == 0) return;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);
        }
        System.out.println("The root is 1.465571 after 15 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
public static void newrap3()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func3(x)/der3(x);
            if (diff == 0) continue;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);
        }
        System.out.println("The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here is the current output

```
66.556258
44.260755
29.39754
19.489335
12.884605
8.482183
5.547478
3.589458
2.277446
1.382632
0.729147
0.100537
-4.269108
-2.99942
-2.190119
-1.719717
-1.511997
-1.467533
-1.465575
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.

66.778557
44.631345
29.867195
20.025493
13.466126
9.09625
6.188412
4.259889
2.993429
2.186424
1.717784
1.511383
1.467482
1.465574
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
1.465571
The root is 1.465571 after 15 iterations.

66.556258
44.260755
29.39754
19.489335
12.884605
8.482183
5.547478
3.589458
2.277446
1.382632
0.729147
0.100537
-4.269108
-2.99942
-2.190119
-1.719717
-1.511997
-1.467533
-1.465575
-1.465572
-1.465572
-1.465572
The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.
```

Comment: How many times do you want to display that message? And at what interval?

Comment: You pretty much put the answer in your question!  You wanted "The root is " + root + " after " + counter + " iterations."  And that's legal Java, if `root` and `counter` are variables.  I.e. `System.out.println("The root is " + root + " after " + counter + " iterations.");`.  All you have to do is define variables `root` and `counter` and make sure they're set to the right values (`root` will be something you've already printed out, so that shouldn't be hard).

Comment: @ajb , how can I set the value of root to be something that is in the for loop? Like I know the root of the first equation is -1.465572, but how can I set root to that value without actually saying 'double root = -1.465572' ?

Comment: @evarias You printed out the value you want.  So set `root` to the same value that you printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general notes:

- your are printing a message that is fixed and you are making 3 times 30 iteration (not 15, 20 and 30 as you write in your message). This `for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)` is always the same.
- I guess the whole spirit of the program is to iterate until it converges, so use 2 variables. One can store the previous value and one the current one. Comparing those 2 variables you can imaging if convergence has occured and `break` the loop. Because the comparison won't give an exact `0` value (`double`s are inaccurate) use a threshold `e` under which your values are considered equal.
- In that sense you can use a `while` loop to let it converge and then exit the loop or use a predefined number of loops using a `for` command and also use `break` when it converges within the given iterations.
- As for the main question you express you can store the root estimation in each iteration and not print it in every loop. Unless you want to see the convergence process.
- Putting `double finalRoot = Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6` in your code for example you can just use it to print after the loop completion. Define it before the loop though so as to be accessible after the loop completion.

Hope that give you a general idea.

Comment: Right. The point is to iterate until it converges. I am not understanding how to use 2 variables to store the previous value and also the current one. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know if you figured it out but anyway but in the beginning of each iteration you store the final root you have in the previous variable and at the end of the iteration you store the newly calculated root value to the current value. So compare those 2 values at the end of each iteration